# Как сделать записи недоступными по прямой ссылке в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, seo

На сайте на Wordpress выводится список неких элементов, например портфолио, на одной странице. Каждый элемент в свою очередь является отдельной записью. Как сделать так, чтобы эти записи не были доступны по прямой ссылке (например: `https://mysite.ru/2017/01/18/nomer-10/` , а только лишь выводились списком на одной странице. Это нужно, чтобы эти записи не индексировались, как самостоятельные страницы сайта.

Код вывода:

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'category_name' => 'portfolio',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
    ));
    if ( $query -> have_posts() ) :  while ( $query ->  have_posts() ) : $query ->  the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $res  = get_field('name_trmplate');
        $prom = explode('|', $res);
        $cur_template = $prom[1];

        $images = array();
        $im = get_the_content();
        preg_match_all('~ title="(.+?)" src="(.+?)" alt="(.+?)"~', $im, $src);
        foreach ($src[0] as $ress) {
            preg_match_all('~title="(.+?)"~', $ress, $title);
            preg_match_all('~src="(.+?)"~', $ress, $im_src);
            preg_match_all('~alt="(.+?)"~', $ress, $alt);
            $images[] = array(
                'SRC'   => $im_src[1][0],
                'TITLE' => $title[1][0],
                'ALT' => $alt[1][0],
            );
        }
        ?>
       <div>Содержимое записи </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для предотвращения индексирования создайте файл robots.txt в корневой папке сайта:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /2017/01/18/*
```

Первые 3 строчки - стандарт для WP, последняя - для редактирования по желанию.

Чтобы сделать недоступными извне страницы-блоки, из содержимого которых вы составляете потом общую страницу, поставьте атрибут "Личное" страницам-блокам. Рабочий пример с одного из сайтов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие страницы не видны никому (кроме автора, если он залогинился), а также поисковым ботам.

Выводить страницу нужно не циклом, а скажем, таким образом:

```
$page = get_page_by_title($atts['title']); 
echo do_shortcode($page->post_content);
```

Ну или в цикле добавить аргумент для WP_Query

```
'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private' )
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант, но он достаточно костыльный. По ссылке страницы все равно доступны и если страниц много и с разными адресами, тоже перечислять все не очень правильно, и в конце-концов при добавлении нового элемента, его придется вносить в robots каждый раз.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, в вопросе написано, что вам надо скрыть это от роботов. Вариант абсолютно не костыльный, а именно для этого стандартом WP и предназначенный. Если проблема в том, что ссылок много, можно генерировать файл robots.txt на лету, как делают SEO плагины. Могу привести пример кода, если надо.

Comment: Звездочку заметили в последней строке? Вы же можете составить нужное вам выражение, чтобы охватить любые url на сайте

Comment: `По ссылке страницы все равно доступны`. Это как понимать? Вы хотите сделать страницы вообще недоступными? А как на них переходить со страницы, где список? ))

Comment: Да, именно совсем недоступными. Список без перехода. Содержимое страниц выводится только лишь на общей страницы. Проще говоря каждая страница представляет собой кусок верстки, из который потом и собирается одна целая.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Если страницам добавить такой статус, то их содержимое на общей странице также не будет отображаться.

Comment: Смотря как вы их выводите. Я этот прием использовал неоднократно. Страницы-блоки недоступны, но на сайте выводятся. На картинке, как можно догадаться, настройки страницы, которая выводится в header сайта. Содержимое у меня выводится через $page->post_content;

Comment: В общем, покажите ваш код.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, вставил код. Он с рабочего сайта, там много лишнего, но суть вроде понятна.

Comment: Нет, в цикле, конечно, не выведет. Я беру страницу $page = get_page_by_title($atts['title']); потом echo do_shortcode($page->post_content); Обновил ответ.

Comment: ` Если страницам добавить такой статус, то их содержимое на общей странице также не будет отображаться.` - дополнил ответ. Можно указать статус постов в цикле. По умолчанию выводится только publish

Comment: Для исключения веб-страницы из индексации примените мета таг noindex https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=ru + https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag . Для блокирования веб-страницы для поисковых роботов, примените директиву Disallow: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html + https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq

Comment: @nikant25 и чего? про disallow я с самого начала написал. Но автору вопроса нужно и сами страницы спрятать.

Comment: Никогда не стоит полагаться на записи в роботсе. Это всего лишь рекомендация, которой ПСы не всегда следуют, а их ботам и вовсе не мешает индексировать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для таких постов (потфолио) я бы создал [кастомный тип постов](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_post_types#Custom_Post_Types), указав `publicly_queryable` или даже `public` как  `false`.